# Trouble adjusting tab-width

Tags: indentation, python, tabs

When I write Python code, I personally prefer indenting with 4 spaces instead of a tab. However, in my day job I work with a codebase that uses only tabs.

When I open one of these files in emacs, tabs display eight spaces wide. I have tried adding both `(setq-default tab-width 4)` and `(setq tab-width 4)` to my init file, but neither of these seem to have any affect on this problem. I have used `whitespace-mode` to confirm that it is indeed one tab that I am seeing and not two, and that they are indeed eight spaces wide. When I check the value of the variable `tab-width` from whatever buffer I am having the problem in, I get the following message:

```
tab-width is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is 8
Local in buffer <whateverbuffer>; global value is 4
```

I know that I want `Its value` to be 4 instead of eight, but I have not had any luck setting it. Also, in the documentation it says of `tab-width`: `Automatically becomes buffer-local when set`...I have a feeling my problem stems from this, but I don't quite understand what this means. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Are you editing those python files using the python mode?

Comment: Yes, I am. And I just noticed that when I change into another mode, the tabs display as I want them too. I am assuming I need to specify in my init for `python-mode` to use a `tab-width` of 8, but not sure how...

Comment: You can use the python-mode-hook to set the tab-width as you want.

Comment: You may need to set `python-indent-offset` also, which should be done outside of the major-mode hook so its customized value is used when `python-mode` first initializes.  If @Nsukami_ could take a look at my draft answer (deleted) and post a proper answer, that would be appreciated.  I'm still not familiar enough with `python-mode` and I don't want to steal @Nsukami_'s thunder.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! Actually, buried in my init file I already set  `python-indent-offset` appropriately, and set `tab-width` using the `python-mode-hook` - my problem was that I was using `setq-default` instead of `setq`. I will research the difference between these two to better understand why it wasn't working the way I had it.

Comment: @Nsukami_, if you post a detailed answer for future readers I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @lawlist Do not understand why you deleted you answer which seems good to me. Please, go ahead, there is no thunder to steal :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line when enabling `python-mode` is `(set (make-local-variable 'tab-width) 8)`.  Because `tab-width` is a buffer-local variable, a new value would need to be set subsequent to the code above.  The most common way this is done is with a major-mode hook, in this case the `python-mode-hook`.

There is also a variable called `python-indent-offset`, which is used when the function `python-indent-guess-indent-offset` can't figure out what indentation to use.  That should be set outside of the major-mode hook so that its custom value is available when `python-mode` first initializes.

```lisp
(setq python-indent-offset 4)

(defun python-custom-settings ()
  (setq tab-width 4))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'python-custom-settings)
```