# Set tab width with no exceptions

Tags: indentation, tabs

I always want the tab width to be 4 spaces, no matter what.  How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to the world of Emacs.  What is you seek is *not* possible -- it is buffer-local, so you'll need to reset it for each major mode that sets it to something you don't like.  Use a major-mode hook to reset it.  The best you can do is set a default -- e.g., `(setq-default tab-width 4)` -- but a major-mode can still change it and you'll need to change it back with a major-mode hook.  Or, do like me, customize the source code of all major-modes you use on a daily basis and take complete control.

Comment: Related: [Trouble adjusting tab-width](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17563/trouble-adjusting-tab-width).